# Change image if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have these two radio buttons where I have hidden the input marks and replaced them with images:

```
<div class="card-block center-style">
    <div class="form-check inline-style">
        <label class="form-check-label question-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="ps-qna-1" id="ps-form-1" value="Homeowner">
            <div class="shadow-active">
                <div class="circle"><img src="images/homeowner.png" id="img-1"><span>Homeowner</span></div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check inline-style">
        <label class="form-check-label question-label">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="ps-qna-1" id="ps-form-2" value="Business">
            <div class="shadow-active">
                <div class="circle"><img src="images/business_servicer.png" id="img-2"><span>Business/Servicer</span></div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the images to swap out if the radio button is selected. If not, I need the image to stay what it is in the HTML. I have this for my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name="ps-qna-1"]:radio').click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=ps-qna-1]:checked').val() == "Homeowner") {
        $("#img-1").attr("src","images/homeowner-active.png");

    } else if ($('input[name=ps-qna-1]:checked').val() == "Business") {
        $("#img-2").attr("src","images/business-servicer-active.png");

    }
});
});
```

But my code is not working. It is not swapping out the images. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is good. Thanks!

I have added two pictures of what the radio buttons look like before selection and how it looks after one is selected. but I need that house image swapped out to a different house image with color in it. Hope this wasn't too confusing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're not setting the image to the inactive version when the user selects the other radio button.

Comment: What is `input[name=user-type]`? How is it related to `input[name=ps-qna-1]`?

Comment: Sorry I just saw that. I changed it to input[name=ps-qna-1] I changed it in my code also. and actually I caught another error. my .val() == "HomeOwner" and I changed it to "Homeowner" (lowercase o) anyways, after doing this, my code is working now, but I can not get it back to the non-active image (the original HTML image) when you select the other radio button. Help? @Barmar

Comment: When you're setting the `-active` URL to one image, set the non-active URL to the other.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I appreciate it! :) @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the `-active` URL to one image, add the normal URL to the other.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="ps-qna-1"]:radio').click(function(){
        switch($(this).val()) {
        case "Homeowner":
            $("#img-1").attr("src","images/homeowner-active.png");
            $("#img-2").attr("src","images/business-service.png");
            break;
        case "Business":
            $("#img-1").attr("src","images/homeowner.png");
            $("#img-2").attr("src","images/business-servicer-active.png");
            break;
        }
    });
});
```